# Why is setonitemclicklistener for listview not working?

Tags: android, listview

I am unable to click on the `ListView`.  I am not getting the toast message.  Click on item is not working.

Relevant code:

```
public class MainActivity5 extends ListActivity {

final Context context = this;
private ImageButton homebutton;
JSONArray customers = null;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private static String url_search_customer = "http://192.168.1.241/myapp/search.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_RESULT = "result";
private static final String TAG_ID = "customer_id";
private static final String TAG_F_NAME = "customer_fname";
private static final String TAG_C_PHONE = "customer_phone";
private static String phNumber;
private static String curActivity;
private static String ID;
private static TextView tvid;
JSONArray result = null;
myObject myObj = new myObject();
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

EditText TextViewName;
EditText TextViewPhone;
private Button buttonNewMember;
private Button buttonSearchAgain;

SessionManager session;

static final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> customerList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    phNumber = i.getStringExtra("phn_no");
    customerList.clear();
    new SearchCustomer().execute();

    ListView lv = this.getListView();
    OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long Clicked " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
}

class SearchCustomer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private boolean successFlag;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity5.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Searching Customer..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String inputPhnNoText = phNumber;

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phno", inputPhnNoText));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_search_customer,
                "POST", params);
        Log.d("Search Response", json.toString());
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    successFlag = true;
                    result = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String fname = c.getString(TAG_F_NAME);
                        String phoneNumber = c.getString(TAG_C_PHONE);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_F_NAME, fname);
                        map.put(TAG_C_PHONE, phoneNumber);
                        customerList.add(map);
                    }
                } else if (success == 0) {
                    successFlag = false;
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MainActivity3.class);
                    i.putExtra("norecords",
                            "No record Found with phone number only ! Try again !!");
                    startActivity(i);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        if (successFlag = true) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity5.this,
                    customerList, R.layout.activity_main5, new String[] {
                            TAG_F_NAME, TAG_C_PHONE, TAG_ID }, new int[] {
                            R.id.TextViewName, R.id.TextViewPhone, R.id.TextViewID });
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        } else if(successFlag = false) {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe, you should have a look on this line :
    ListView lv = getListView(); (to understand if you really point to the right listview. Do you have a ListActivity or ListFragment ?)

Comment: Sir, I have extended ListActivity..

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in onCreate() method before this line `new SearchCustomer().execute();`

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selectedID = TAG_ID;
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Congratulations.class);
        i.putExtra("selectedID", selectedID);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: @jt. Are you extend ListActivity, Right?

Comment: I have set "map.put(TAG_ID, id)" in doInBackground method, where it is set the ID of the Customer in database.. that ID I need to pass in the second Activity..

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below:

```
     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor cursorID= (Cursor)lv.getItemAtPosition(position); 
                String selectedID = lv.getString(1); 
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Congratulations.class);
                i.putExtra("selectedID", selectedID);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hello Avadhani
I put this code made with some changes as per eclipse gave as an error, but still not working..

final ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
Cursor cursorID= (Cursor)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
String selectedID = ((Cursor) lv).getString(1);
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Congratulations.class);
i.putExtra("selectedID", selectedID);
startActivity(i);
}
});
So Need to make any other changes..

Answer (score 0):

When you use ListActivity override this method to get clicks/

```
onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView, android.view.View, int, long)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView, android.view.View, int, long)

Comment: Thanks, I have wrote @Override before "public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {" But, its giving error in eclipse to Remove '@Override' annotation.. and that is function is called even in postExecution method or onCreate method.. still not working.. :(

Comment: to teach eclipse to know annotations such as override, set in project settings sdk version 1.6

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work in AsyncTask class. write the onItemClickListner in onCreate() method 
if the condition is fail in AsyncTask class it automatically calls the other activity.

if the codition is success then you can view the ListView in that activity...